# Missing method NeuralNet.train_split() in lasagne

Tags: python-3.x, theano, lasagne

I am learning to deal with python and lasagne. I have following installed on my pc:

- python 3.4.3
- theano 0.9.0
- lasagne 0.2.dev1

and also six, scipy and numpy. I call `net.fit()`, and the stacktrace tries to call `train_split(X, y, self)`, which, I guess, should split the samples into training set and validation set (both the inputs X as well as the outputs Y).

But there is no method like `train_split(X, y, self)` , there is only a float field `train_split` - I assume, the ratio between training and validation set sizes. Then I get following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "...\workspaces\python\cnn\dl_tutorial\lasagne\Test.py", line
>   72, in 
>       net = net1.fit(X[0:10,:,:,:],y[0:10])
>
> File "...\Python34\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.py", line
>   544, in fit
>       self.train_loop(X, y, epochs=epochs)
>
> File "...\Python34\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.py", line
>   554, in train_loop
>       X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = self.train_split(X, y, self)
>
> TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

What could be wrong or missing? Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

in previous versions, the input parameter `train_split` has been a number, that was used by the same-named method. In nolearn 0.6.0, it's a callable object, that can implement its own logic to split the data. So instead of providing a float number to the input parameter `train_split`, I have to provide a callable instance (the default one is `TrainSplit`), that will be executed in each training epoch.